# Build errors after adding fullscreen activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm experimenting with my first "Hello World"-like application in Android Studio. I've tried to add a new activity (first via New -> Android Component, didn't like the result, deleted it, then via New -> Activity -> selected Fullscreen activity). Now I get these errors:

```
  Gradle: Execution failed for task ':LanguagesMemorizer:processDebugResources'.
  > Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':LanguagesMemorizer:processDebugResources'
  C:\...\src\main\res\values\attrs.xml
    Gradle: Attribute "buttonBarStyle" has already been defined
    Gradle: Attribute "buttonBarButtonStyle" has already been defined
```

I've tried searching for buttonBarStyle in my project. It was found in:

- build folder (I guess I should ignore that, shouldn't I?)
- layout file for a new activity (style="?buttonBarStyle")
- values\attrs.xml itself (`<declare-styleable ...> <attr name="buttonBarStyle" format="reference" /> ...`)
- values\styles.xml (`<style...>... <item name="buttonBarStyle">@style/ButtonBar</item>...`)
- values-v11\styles.xml (`<style...>...<item name="buttonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>...`)

All of it was auto-generated. How should I fix this error?

UPDATE: There is a comment in attrs.xml which says

```
<!-- Declare custom theme attributes that allow changing which styles are
         used for button bars depending on the API level.
         ?android:attr/buttonBarStyle is new as of API 11 so this is
         necessary to support previous API levels. -->
```

So it seems like these attributes are needed for old Androids, but so I guess there is some sort of a conflict between API 11-declared attributes and these manual attributes. How should I fix them?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is because `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0` already has this attribute. So if you plan to use this support library (and you should) it is safe to just delete declaration of this attributes from your project `\src\main\res\values\attrs.xml`. I guess, this duplication is because AndroidStudio new activity wizard, doesn't suppose that you can use support library so it generates all code by itself.