# Adding v7 android support library to existing project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

When I added appcompact v7 library to exising project, error occurs in xml file 
"error: Attribute "buttonBarStyle" has already been defined". [See Screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/3ccaf85c-c7b6-4427-8c39-b88043cd146c/4652e13d4386160ea62a5d6959adfc2e)

> [image]

I downloaded the project sample form http://developer.oovoo.com/

Comment: You click on **Is Library**?

Comment: @ Kanwaljit Singh, i did not understand your question.Please be clear.

Comment: In image see there is one checkbox **Is Library**. You click on that checkbox or not?

Comment: Thanks @ Kanwaljit Singh, i did not check. Should i check the Check box?

Comment: If still any problem you can ask me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your styleable is defined in your project RES folder. That styleable is also defined in the v7 support library, so it is now defined twice. Remove it from your RES xml.

See this answer and post: [Build errors after adding fullscreen activity in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632137/build-errors-after-adding-fullscreen-activity-in-android-studio?answertab=votes#tab-top)