# Error after adding AppCompat v7 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-appcompat

After adding the appCompat v7 library I get the error that R cannot be resolved, which is apparently due to the fact that R now exists twice. I found an answer to that problem here : [Build errors after adding fullscreen activity in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632137/build-errors-after-adding-fullscreen-activity-in-android-studio)

However, I dont have or cant find the file attrs.xml in \src\main\res\values\attrs.xml. Is there any other solution to that problem or can someone give me a detailed description of how to do that in Android Studio?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your /app/build.gradle file :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
}
```

and make sure the version code (here 18.0.0) is not higher than the buildToolsVersion in the same file :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.0"
}
```

then rebuild your project. Hope that helps!
Oh and make sure you have the right buildTools installed via SDK Manager! Actual version is 21.0.2 I think.

Comment: Thank you very much! In my case I set the buildToolsVersion on 21.0.1 and appcompat is 21.0.0 then it worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm may be noob, but after several search i was able to add appcompat.v7 in android studio.

Initially i was comfortable with Eclipse after Dex Error 65535, my whole hard work was doomed i thought.

As Honey suggested you have to add both support.v4 or v13 and appcompat.v7 in build.gradle.

That's it. This simple solution not even covered in google docs ;). A simple reminder appcompat depends on v4 or v13.